# Почему при добавлении нового кода он перестает работать?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```js
let balance = 0;
[...document.querySelectorAll(".itemAdd")].forEach(item => {
  
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = document.querySelector(".item_price").textContent;
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""),);
    balance = balance + sum;
    alert("balance = " + balance);
    localStorage.setItem("balance" , JSON.stringify(balance))

document.getElementById('purse').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('balance');


   if (balance > 0){
    document.getElementById('empty_card').hidden = true;
  };    
  });
});
```

```html
<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"></a><i class="itemAdd"></i></a><span class="item_price"> 310</span></h4>
```

но при добавление этого кода:

```js
document.getElementById('hider').onclick = function() {
    alert(balance / 2);  
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hider" value="поделить balance на 2"/>
```

первый код перестаёт работать. Можете помочь пофиксить или исправить ну или хотяб обяснить почему оно не работает буду благодарен.

Comment: Перестаёт работать. Пишет в консоль какую-то ошибку?

Comment: _при добавление этого кода_ - куда ты добавляешь этот код? Какой код в итоге получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поправил относительно своего понимания сути проблемы:

```js
let balance = 0
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_add")).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = document.querySelector(".item_price").textContent
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""),)
    balance = balance + sum
    alert("balance = " + balance)
  })
})

document.querySelector("#hider").addEventListener("click", () => alert(balance / 2))
```

```html
<h4>
  <a class="item_add" href="#">
    <i class="itemAdd"><span class="item_price">310</span></i>
  </a>
</h4>

<input type="button" id="hider" value="поделить balance на 2" />
```